# Web Serial API won't read all data

Tags: javascript, serial-port

sometimes it can read all data,but sometimes it won't, it just stop it in the middle, how do I do to make it always read all data after releaseLock?
here's the write and read code

```
async function writeSerial_BMSA() {
    try {
        writer = port.writable.getWriter();
        let commandframe = new Uint8Array([
            0x42,
            0x4D,
            0x53,
            0x41,
        ]);
        commandframe = NACTRAU_Send(commandframe);
        await writer.write(commandframe);
        log.innerHTML = commandframe;
        writer.releaseLock();
        write_times++;
    } catch (error) {
        log.innerHTML = error;
    }
}
```

```
async function readSerial_BMSA() {
    try {
        reader = port.readable.getReader();
        try {
            while (true) {
                const { value, done } = await reader.read();
                if (done) {
                    reader.releaseLock();
                    break;
                }
                if (value.length > 1) {
                    let FWV = "";
                    let U_len = value[2] - 4;
                    for (let i = 0; i < U_len; i++) {
                        value[i] = value[i + 6];
                        FWV += String.fromCharCode(value[i]);
                    }
                    read_times++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            log.innerHTML = error;
        } finally {
            console.log(port.readable);
            reader.releaseLock();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        log.innerHTML = error;
    }
}
```

I tried put the code in the`if (done){}` but it's not working.
The result suppose like this
`new Uint8Array([49, 48, 45, 48, 55, 45, 66, 44, 65, 117, 103, 32, 50, 55, 32, 50, 48, 50, 49, 32, 49, 56, 58, 52, 56, 58, 50, 53, 32, 44, 48, 50, 48, 55, 44, 56, 48, 50, 48, 44, 49, 48, 44, 48, 50, 44, 49, 48, 44, 48, 50, 74, 226])`

wrong ones be like
`new Uint8Array([49, 48, 45, 48, 55, 45, 66, 44, 65, 117, 103, 32, 50, 55, 32, 50, 48, 50, 49, 32, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`

Answer (score 0):

It might chunk the scanned data.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/serial

check this document out.
use textDecoderStream and put the chunk data together.